# How can ICE Console font display two accents aigu (é) with 0233 and 0130

Tags: fonts, character-encoding, putty

How is windows mapping character codes to a font like ICE Console? I have a particular case.

I have noticed that ICE Console will display alt+0130 and alt+0233 as é. The glyph seems slightly different.
[Notepad ICE Console Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfC9n.png)

Another example, in linux using putty, translation setting "use font encoding", the results are the same as above.  Same results in microsoft word.

Using character map in windows. I cannot locate the glyph accent aigu 0130, but I can locate  0233.

How is windows able to locate the glyph é in ICE Console with both 0130 and 0233 ?

I am trying to understand how fonts are mapped to character codes, so I can troubleshoot database issue where codepages CP437 and ISO8859-1 are mixed.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Are you sure you meant alt+0130, and not alt+130?